# How to view and record video simultaneously using EmguCV?

Tags: c#, video, save, video-capture, emgucv

I'm working on Windows Form App, which is similar to surveillance system  and tried to capture and save video simultaneously. I am able to view video from camera but when tried to save video. An empty video file is generated.

As I'm totally new to emguCV, I'm stuck and could not resolve it.

Here is what I have Tried

```
 VideoCapture videoCapture;
        double totalFrames;
        double fps;
        VideoWriter videoWriter;
        DateTime dateTime;
        int i;

        public Body()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            i = 0;

           
                if (videoCapture == null)
                {
                    dateTime = new DateTime();
                    dateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    videoCapture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(0);
                }
                videoCapture.ImageGrabbed += VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed;
                videoCapture.Start();

              

        }

        private void VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Mat m = new Mat();
            videoCapture.Retrieve(m);
            pictureBox1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;

            totalFrames = videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount);
            fps = videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);

            if (videoCapture == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                int fourcc = Convert.ToInt32(videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FourCC));
                int frameHeight = Convert.ToInt32(videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight));
                int frameWidth = Convert.ToInt32(videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth));
                string destination = "C:\\Users\\ITNOA\\Desktop\\savedVideoDHS\\" + i+".mp4";
                videoWriter = new VideoWriter(destination, fourcc, fps, new Size(frameWidth, frameHeight), true);
                videoWriter.Write(m);
            }


        }

private void videoSavingtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            videoCapture = null;
            i++;
            if (videoWriter.IsOpened)
            {
                videoWriter.Dispose();
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how one can view and save video at same time using emgu cv.

```
public Body()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
                if (videoCapture == null)
                {
                  
                    videoCapture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(0);
                }
                videoCapture.ImageGrabbed += VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed;
                videoCapture.Start();

              

        }

        private void VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileChanged)
            {
                totalFrames = videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount);
                fps = videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);
                int fourcc = Convert.ToInt32(videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FourCC));
                int frameHeight = Convert.ToInt32(videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight));
                int frameWidth = Convert.ToInt32(videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth));
                string destination = "C:\\Users\\ITNOA\\Desktop\\savedVideoDHS\\" + i + ".avi";
                videoWriter = new VideoWriter(destination, VideoWriter.Fourcc('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V'), fps, new Size(frameWidth, frameHeight), true);
                fileChanged = false;
            }

           
            Mat m = new Mat();
            videoCapture.Retrieve(m);
            pictureBox1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;
            videoWriter.Write(m);
        }
```

In above code as I needed to save video into multiple files, I'm re initializing video-writer. For single file it be should initialized once.

I tried multiple compression codes but following worked for me

**Compression code  VideoWriter.Fourcc('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V')**

> videoWriter = new VideoWriter(destination, VideoWriter.Fourcc('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V'),
> fps, new Size(frameWidth, frameHeight), true);